# 2008 ServerCore, Local Administrator Password Reset, Still Can't Login

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

Running Server 2008 Server Core and I cannot login via the local administrator account. Since it wouldn’t take my “correct credentials”, I reset the local administrator password using other known methods. Yet, still even now with a blank password, I still get the the “user or password is incorrect” message when using the administrator username.

Also, what I found strange, was when I reset the password for the administrator account, it showed the failed attempts for the administrator account, and it was zero. That couldn’t be right, because I had tried at least 20 or 30 times. So, something strange is going on here, and I’m almost at the point of just reinstalling it, but I’m hoping someone can explain why this is happening.

I mention the following because I’m sure many will think the issue is I’m still trying to logon to the domain. I have used the .\administrator for the username to force windows to login using the local administrator account, and it even shows the local computer name on the login screen, so again, not sure why it’s not working.

Comment: If it's on a domain, does an alternate server have the ability to attach via Computer Mgmt and then login with an alternate local admin account (if you can create one)?

Comment: And you're certain that the local Administrator account is enabled?